# jQuery .attr() not responding as expected

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a text field that holds a difference between days. I need to use it calculate something on my page. However, for some reason it is coming back as `undefined` when I do a `console.log()`. Any ideas?

```
<script>
        $(document).on('change', '#unitselector', function()
        {
            var unit = $('select option:selected').text();
            var rate = $(this).val();
            var tax = $('select option:selected').attr('label');
            var depart=$('#departdate').val();
            var arrival = $('#arrivaldate').val();
            var dataString = {unit:unit, depart:depart, arrival:arrival};
            console.log(dataString);
            //console.log($('.extracharges').serialize());
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "classes/unit_info.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $('.unitinfolist').html(html);
                }
            });

            var days = $('#days').attr('name');
            var days2 = $('#days').attr('value');
            console.log('days: '+days);
            console.log('days: '+ days2 );
            $('.rentalcharges').find('#rent').val(rate*days);
        });
    </script>
```

and the PHP

```
$arrive = $_POST['arrival'];
$leave = $_POST['depart'];

$a = date_create($arrive);
$d = date_create($leave);
$diff = date_diff($d,$a);

echo '<input type="text" id="days" value="'.$diff->d.'" name="'.$diff->d.'" />';
```

Comment: please post the relevant HTML.. do you have duplicate IDs in your html?

Comment: Can you post the outputted HTML (copied from source, not written out manually) for that input field?

Comment: Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for form control values. Also, I'm guessing you should probably move the last 5 lines into the AJAX success handler. Otherwise, the `#days` element probably won't be present

Comment: I already tried .val() and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Isn't the relevant html listed? The jQuery sends `dataString` to the PHP and it creates that `input`. That input displays the proper number; I can see it. It just isn't getting it in the jQuery for some reason.

Comment: Is the `#days` input which gets echoed by PHP something which is returned from the `.ajax()` call? Is that what is put into the element with class `unitinfolist` in the success method? If so, the code which tries to find that input and get the name/value is not finding anything because it is executing before the ajax request returns. Search SO for questions regarding async code and execution order regarding ajax.

Comment: @user2690363 The last 5 lines will be executing before the AJAX request has completed, hence why they should be inside the `success` callback

Comment: @user2690363 no the relevant HTML isn't listed.  PHP that outputs HTML is shown however there is no guarantee that it outputs what you expect, and we can't guess that. You should post the output. By the way Phil knows the answer, and has left it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax call is asynchronous so even though you have the logging code written after the ajax call you are logging the values before they have been returned from the server.

Move your code into the ajax success handler like so:

```
<script>
        $(document).on('change', '#unitselector', function()
        {
            var unit = $('select option:selected').text();
            var rate = $(this).val();
            var tax = $('select option:selected').attr('label');
            var depart=$('#departdate').val();
            var arrival = $('#arrivaldate').val();
            var dataString = {unit:unit, depart:depart, arrival:arrival};
            console.log(dataString);
            //console.log($('.extracharges').serialize());
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "classes/unit_info.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $('.unitinfolist').html(html);
                    var days = $('#days').attr('name');
                    var days2 = $('#days').attr('value');
                    console.log('days: '+days);
                    console.log('days: '+ days2 );
                    $('.rentalcharges').find('#rent').val(rate*days);
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate question and should have been flagged as such with a link to the duplicated in the comments.

Comment: Ummm. Feel free to do so then. Jeez

Comment: I did, after determining that it was the case. I am simply pointing it out to you since you left an answer on it. No offense intended, just pointing out SO protocol.

Comment: And Phil should have posted this anyway

Comment: @popnoodles I knew it was a duplicate but was too lazy to find the other post :)